# Why do I get 'int is not subscriptable' error message?

Tags: python, binary, int

I'm making a binary to decimal converter, and we can't use int() or bin(). I THINK I've gotten the code correct, except it keeps telling me "int is not subscriptable"! HELP!

```
binaryNum = input("Enter a binary number: ") decimalNum = 0 count=0

while(int(binaryNum))>0:
    count=count+1
    binaryNum=int(binaryNum)//10
    power = count

while power >= 0:
    if int(binaryNum[power]) == '1': #here is the problem
        decimalNum += 2**power
        power -= 1


print(decimalNum)
```

Comment: There's several issues in that line. First, `binaryNum` is an integer, which is what the error is telling you - `[power]` is more like the syntax for indexing a list or looking up values in a dictionary by key; you cannot index an integer. It's not clear what you wish that syntax to be. Had that syntax worked, you explicitly convert the result to an integer and then try to compare it with a string (`'1'`) which cannot be True.

Comment: Well - think it through logically. Either you know all the answers and can figure it out yourself; or else you need to ask a more precise question. Do you know what an `int` is? Do you know what a subscript is? Do you understand which line of the code the error is complaining about? Do you understand why it wouldn't make sense to subscript an `int`? Do you see where a subscript operation occurs on that line? Do you know which value is being subscripted? Do you understand why that value would be an `int` at that point in the code?

Comment: If you are not allowed use `int()` or `bin()`, then why do you have `int(binaryNum)`?

Comment: When asking about an error, identify the problem line (the traceback).  Look for subscripting in that line.  What's the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply like this, ( `ord` function will return ASCII value of the given number therefore if you subtract the number from 48 which is ASCII value of '0' you will convert the number easily )

```
binary = input('enter a number: ')
decimal = 0
for digit in binary:
    digit = ord(digit) - 48 
    decimal = decimal*2 + digit
print(decimal)
```

if you don't want to use extra functions you can do it like  this

```
binary = input('enter a number: ')
decimal = 0
for digit in binary:
    digit = 1 if digit == '1' else 0
    decimal = decimal*2 + digit
print(decimal)
```

And your problem reason is you can't iterate a integer

```
while(int(binaryNum))>0:
    count=count+1
    binaryNum=int(binaryNum)//10 ### here you assign binaryNum as integer
    power = count

while power >= 0:
    if int(binaryNum[power]) == '1': ### and you cant iterate binaryNum because it is an integer
        decimalNum += 2**power
        power -= 1
```

Comment: sorry but could u explain 'digit'? What does it do in this code?

Comment: @batteredandspicy, we take `binaryNum` as string therefore  strings are iterable object. Digit means one digit in the `binNum` string (you can consider iterable objects like an array)

Answer (score 0):

After the first loop, `binaryNum` is a number, not a string.

The point of the restriction is that you should not convert the input to a number at all, and you're using `int` *three* times, which is three times more than you're allowed.

Instead, loop over the digits in the input string.
On every iteration, multiply by two.
If the digit is `'1'`, add one to the result.

```
binaryNum = input("Enter a binary number: ")
number = 0
for digit in binaryNum:
    number *= 2
    if digit == '1':
        number += 1
```